# Upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.2.5

Tags: magento2.2.2

how can I upgrade my Magento 2.2.2, when composer is not available? Upgrade in backand also not possible. PHP Limit.

It is a hosting provider and I have no composer or backend update. Only SSH, FTP and Database connect.

Thank you!

Comment: So you can't see any composer.json file in the root of your project via ssh?

Comment: You are restricted far too much by the hosting provider.  You should switch to a different hosting provider or hosting package.  My guess is that you are unable to SSH into the account and have enough access for composer.  What version of PHP?  Nginx or Apache?  Check the 2.2.5 requirements to ensure you are even able to upgrade.  
Are you able to use git from SSH?

Comment: Hello! I have SSH access ... but the user is limidet and can´t install the composer.